# does gpref and python required to create module from Titanium studio?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

I am using Titanium Studio, build: 3.4.1.201410281727.
When I try to publish a sample module from studio, I am getting below error

```
process.annotations:
BUILD FAILED
C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.4.1.GA\module\android\build.xml:163: Class not found: javac1.8

Total time: 709 milliseconds
```

I don't find Application Data in my c drive but rest of the path.
do I need to install gpref and python required to create module from Titanium studio?
I have android SDK as well as NDK, ANT,eclipse java tools and ADT.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your ANT cannot find javac compiler. Check the PATH variables.

Run `javac --version` from the command line and see if it's found.

Comment: PATH variables are fine. javac -version is working fine.